# How to make google chart using ajax and json in django?

Tags: html, json, django, ajax, google-maps

I want to insert google chart using json file. 
this is the one views.py function to load json file. => 
def get_addresses(request):
    addresses = Address.objects.all().values('address', 'postalcode', 'country', 'latitude', 'longitude')
    addresses_list = list(addresses) 
    return JsonResponse(addresses_list, safe=False)

and this is one of the example of json => [{"address": "\uc11c\uc6b8 \uac15\ub0a8\uad6c \uac1c\ud3ec2\ub3d9 ", "postalcode": "135993", "country": "Republic of Korea", "latitude": "37.4896011", "longitude": "127.0687685"}

I don't know why it doesn't show up google chart. 
I got the address from google map api randomly generated. I think google chart could read the address which looks like a key or something. 
So I don't think it's the problem of address. 
Can anyone please tell what is the problem?

```
  <html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" 
  src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'> 
  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['geochart'],
       // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
      //  See: 



      'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyBZ20X5YvOthFtpf48PMJbCek6456cfSTM'
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);


     function drawMarkersMap() {
     var jsonData = $.ajax({
         url: "senders_list.json",
         dataType: "json",
         async: false
         }).responseText;       

     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

     var options = {
       region: 'KR',
       displayMode: 'markers',
       colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
     };

     var chart = new 
    google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

 }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```